# PHP Warning: date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php

It may be a very basic question but I am unable to understand whats wrong with the following code

```
$currentDateTime = new DateTime( date(), 'Europe/London' );
```

it throws following warning

> PHP Warning:  date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $date->date; // It will return current date time at your specified timezone
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to supply FORMAT to the `date()` as parameter. you can use as follows.

```
$currentDateTime = new DateTime( date("Y-m-d"),new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a param / format inside [`date()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp) like this:

```
$currentDateTime = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'Europe/London' );
```

Hope this helps!